# Shopware hook LegacyStructConverter problems

Tags: events, hook, shopware

I`m trying subscribe hook for public method convertListProductStruct of LegacyStructConverter.
*Path \Shopware\Components\Compatibility\LegacyStructConverter*

My code:

```
$this->subscribeEvent(
            'LegacyStructConverter::convertListProductStruct::after',
            'afterListProductStruct'
    );
```

But event does not appear :( What I`m doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LegacyStructConverter is not hookable.
Please see: https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/shopware-5-core-service-extensions/